# Generating C declarations

Tags: c, syntax, declaration

Much has been written on the topic of how to parse C declarations.

I need to do the reverse: Take a tree representation of a type, together with the variable name, and print out a corresponding declaration as it would appear in C source code.

Has anyone written down an algorithm for doing this, in available form?

(I tried looking at https://github.com/ridiculousfish/cdecl-blocks which seems as though it must contain such a thing, but I have been able to find in it, code for doing everything related to its functionality *except* generating C declarations.)

Comment: So you need to “pretty print” the AST into C source? If so, check pycparser and the examples for a Python library that can do that

Comment: I would take a look at the EBNF grammar in [the language Standard.](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf) The problem you want to solve is generating sentences.

Comment: For relatively simple types, it's probably a matter of checking the AST representation for each qualifier in the order that it should appear. The main complication is something like `const foo (*const array_of_foo)[N];`

Comment: @MortenJensen Looking through the code of pycparser, I am seeing lots of code for parsing the C source to AST, but nothing for vice versa. What am I missing?

Comment: @rwallace see my answer below, it's hiding in `examples/c-to-c.py`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eli Bendersky's Python library [pycparser](https://github.com/eliben/pycparser/) has an example, parsing C-code to an AST-representation, and pretty-prints it, converting it to C-code again.

The specific example I am thinking of [can be found here](https://github.com/eliben/pycparser/blob/master/examples/c-to-c.py), and the part I think is of interest to you, is this:

```
def _zz_test_translate():
    # internal use
    src = r'''
    void f(char * restrict joe){}
    int main(void)
    {
        unsigned int long k = 4;
        int p = - - k;
        return 0;
    }
    '''
    parser = c_parser.CParser()
    ast = parser.parse(src)
    ast.show()
    generator = c_generator.CGenerator()

    print(generator.visit(ast))
```

So what this example does, is it parses C -> AST from string (`src`). Then it pretty-prints the AST (`ast.show()`). Then it turns the AST into C source code and prints it out.

This example uses the `c_generator` module [which can be found here](https://github.com/eliben/pycparser/blob/master/pycparser/c_generator.py).
It is a class with a `visit`-method that traverses an AST and spits out C code.

I've used it for instrumenting C code, e.g. inserting code at the beginning of function calls or return-points. It should be possible to define struct-decls programmatically and then convert them to C.

From your description it sounds like this could be of use? Either directly: from AST-format -> C source, or as an inspirational source for your own work.

**Can you provide a few examples of the struct-decls you wish to convert to C code?**